# database lost on docker restart

Tags: database, docker, influxdb, grafana

I'm running influxdb and grafana on Docker with Windows 10.

Every time I shut down Docker, I lose my database.

Here's what I know:

- I have tried adjusting the retention policies, with no effect on the
  outcome
- I can shut down and restart the containers (docker-compose down) and the database is still there. Only when I shut down Docker for Windows do I lose the database.
- I don't see any new folders on the mapped directory when I create a new database (/data/influxdb/data/)'. Only the '_internal' folder persists, which I assume corresponds to the persisting database called '_internal'

Here's my yml file. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Define an InfluxDB service
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    volumes:
      - ./data/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
      - "80:80"
      - "8083:8083"
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    volumes:
      - ./data/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - 'env.grafana'
    links:
      - influxdb
  # Define a service for using the influx CLI tool.
  # docker-compose run influxdb-cli
  influxdb-cli:
    image: influxdb
    entrypoint:
      - influx
      - -host
      - influxdb
    links:
      - influxdb
```

Comment: What is the behavior when you use an absolute path to define the place where  you persist your data? Like: `/var/lib/data/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using `docker-compose down/up`, keep in mind that **this is not a "restart"** because:

- [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) **creates new** containers and
- [`docker-compose down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) **removes them** :

> ### docker-compose up
>
> Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.
>
> ### docker-compose down
>
> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.

So, `removing the containers` + `not using a mechanism to persist data` (such as [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)) means that you lose your data ☹️

On the other hand, if you keep using:

- `docker-compose start`
- `docker-compose stop`
- `docker-compose restart`

you deal with the same containers, the ones created when you ran `docker-compose up`.

Comment: This was totally the problem! Thank you!

Comment: docker-compose down should not delete volume unless you remove the volume manually.

Comment: docker-compose down should not delete volume unless you remove the volume manually. the problem as mentioned by Anish is the new version of influxdb dir structure which in v2 has changed to /var/lib/influxdb2

Answer (score 3):

```
docker-compose down
```

the above command should not remove the volume unless specified.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

I tried the following docker-compose.yaml file which persist the data even with down or rm docker commands.

```
version: '3'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    volumes:
      - influxdb-data:/var/lib/influxdb2
    restart: always
volumes:
  influxdb-data:
    external: true
```

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is related to mounted volume not docker or influxdb. You should first find where influxdb stores data(by default it is in your home folder "~user/. influxdb" in windows)  and then generate influxdb.conf file, finally mount the volumes.

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to work for me but just in case someone else is reading this for the same problem as mine, the connection with my Docker Wordpresscompose site was lost.
It seems as though it needed restarting.

I used the advice from @tgogos and into the shell terminal in the docker root folder I typed the command:

```
docker-compose restart
```

however before doing this i edited the yml file, docker-compose.yml to also include:

```
restart: always
```

with the advice from the [linode.com site](https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/wordpress-with-docker-compose/)