# Uvicorn suddenly throwing 500 Internal Server error

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn, testdriven.io

Goinging through the Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker course on testdriven dot io and I'm suddenly getting a 500 Internal Server error from Uvicorn. I have my code in git so I'm pretty sure there are no changes there that shouldn't be. Any help appreciated:

Here's the stack trace from the docker container:

```
ERROR:uvicorn.error:Exception in ASGI application

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 369, in run_asgi

result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 59, in __call__

return await self.app(scope, receive, send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__

await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__

await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__

raise exc from None

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__

await self.app(scope, receive, _send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__

raise exc from None

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__

await self.app(scope, receive, sender)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__

await route.handle(scope, receive, send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle

await self.app(scope, receive, send)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app

response = await func(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 201, in app

raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 148, in run_endpoint_function

return await dependant.call(**values)

File "./app/api/summaries.py", line 22, in create_summary

summary_id = await crud.post(payload)

File "./app/api/crud.py", line 15, in post

await summary.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/models.py", line 923, in save

await executor.execute_insert(self)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/backends/base/executor.py", line 203, in execute_insert

insert_result = await self.db.execute_insert(self.insert_query, values)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/backends/asyncpg/client.py", line 38, in translate_exceptions_

raise OperationalError(exc)

tortoise.exceptions.OperationalError: relation "textsummary" does not exist
```

Comment: This is the error: `tortoise.exceptions.OperationalError: relation "textsummary" does not exist`. It's probably a column missing in your database or a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a problem with your database schema. I suppose tortoise orm is trying to insert new data in your summary table but "textsummary" (field/relation to other table) does not exist. Try to check your schema and maybe make a migration.

If you build fresh docker container with db and app make sure you execute migration script during the container building

Comment: Thanks digoya I think that the problem alright. I don't understand though why this is a problem as I didn't change the schema and I've delete the local images etc. and rebuilt them. Basically a noob but so why I'm struggling. Leave it with me and I'll try and figure it out and I'll post here when I get to the root of the problem.

Comment: I believe this may help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332305/database-lost-on-docker-restart#48378247) Docker may deleted existing database while rebuilding containers. Therefore after rebuild you get fresh and clear database. To preserve database files you can specify external volume in docker-compose.yaml

Comment: yeah you were spot on.

First up apologies for the delay. I took a weeks staycation and didn't bring the laptop.

Second. Yeah as part of the course the schema creation was moved out of the startup, for obvious reasons, and needed to be explicitly created.

All sorted now.

Comment: I'm following the same tutorial and had the same problem. This answer solved my question, I would also like to add that to run the migration on this tutorial we have tu run: `docker-compose exec web python app/db.py`

Answer (score 0):

The following change will allow automatic creation of data-tables.

```
def init_db(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    register_tortoise(
        app,
        db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"),
        modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
        generate_schemas=True,
        add_exception_handlers=True,
    )
```

This should solve the problems - `generate_schemas=True` was changed a couple of steps before, and probably this is the best way to go - they just did not write it that you need to revert to the previous version.